# When is it appropriate to challenge with a secret word?

Tags: passwords, authentication

Lets say a secret word is say, the name of your first pet. Mother's maiden name is also a common one.

When does it make sense to challenge the user with this? Or, what actions should be secured by a secret word?

I'm just not sure I know the security value of a secret work, what its intrinsic value is over a password.

Comment: How is that word secret? I mean, my bank knows the same mothers maiden name that my phone company knows. And as far as I know it's not even unusual or surprising that I have only one mother!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would never ever use any of those questions to reset a password. You are actually making your password scheme more vulnerable as finding out secret questions with easy to find answers is not  that hard.

Bruce Schneier had an an [excellent blog post titled The Curse of the Secret Questions](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/the_curse_of_th.html) on this:

> The point of all these questions is the same: a backup password. If
>   you forget your password, the secret question can verify your identity
>   so you can choose another password or have the site e-mail your
>   current password to you. It's a great idea from a customer service
>   perspective -- a user is less likely to forget his first pet's name
>   than some random password -- but terrible for security. The answer to
>   the secret question is much easier to guess than a good password, and
>   the information is much more public. (I'll bet the name of my family's
>   first pet is in some database somewhere.) And even worse, everybody
>   seems to use the same series of secret questions. The result is the
>   normal security protocol (passwords) falls back to a much less secure
>   protocol (secret questions). And the security of the entire system
>   suffers.

Comment: That's why my secret question's answer is also randomly generated :)

Comment: Normally they're only spam protection. If you answer the secret questions correctly, they email you a password reset token. Only retarded websites (unfortunately not a rare attribute) use public questions to directly change the password.